# wxListBox - Segmentation fault

Tags: c++, linux, segmentation-fault, wxwidgets

For hours I've been trying to learn how to use **wxListBox** from *wxWidgets*. I've based my "application" on official [tutorial](http://zetcode.com/tutorials/wxwidgetstutorial/widgetsII/) but I can't get it working even though my code is not that different from original.

I want to add a new item to wxListBox but instead I get **Segmentation fault**. Here's my code:

```
class CWindow : public wxFrame {
    wxBoxSizer      *hbox, *vbox;
    wxListBox           *list;
    wxButton            *btnAdd, *btnRemove;

public:
    CWindow(int w = 640, int h = 480) : wxFrame(NULL, -1, wxT("Test"), wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(w, h)) {
        list = new wxListBox(this, wxID_ANY, wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(w-100, h));
        btnAdd = new wxButton(this, -1, wxT("Add"));
        btnAdd->Connect(wxEVT_COMMAND_BUTTON_CLICKED, (wxObjectEventFunction) &CWindow::OnNew);
        btnRemove = new wxButton(this, -1, wxT("Remove"));

        vbox = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);
        vbox->Add(btnAdd, 1, wxALL | wxEXPAND, 0);
        vbox->Add(btnRemove, 1, 0, 0);

        hbox = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);
        hbox->Add(list, 1, 0, 0);
        hbox->Add(vbox, 0, 0, 0);

        SetSizer(hbox);
    }

    void OnNew(wxCommandEvent &event) {
        wxString str = wxGetTextFromUser(wxT("New item:"));
        if (str.Len() > 0) list->InsertItems(1, &str, 0); //this line is suspected of causing segfault
    }
};
```

Any ideas what's causing my issue?

PS. The tutorial example works just fine so library bug is not a possibility.

EDIT:
*gdb* debugger reports this:

```
0x00007ffff7a8e492 in wxListBoxBase::InsertItems(unsigned int, wxString const*, unsigned int) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwx_gtk2u_core-2.8.so.0
```

EDIT2: more *gdb* dumps
Before:

```
    Breakpoint 1, CWindow::OnNew (this=0x725cd0, event=...) at listbox.cpp:32
    32 if (str.Len() > 0) list->InsertItems(1, &str, 0);
(gdb) print list
    warning: can't find linker symbol for virtual table for `CWindow' value
    $1 = (wxListBox *) 0x0
(gdb) up
    #1  0x00007ffff7586d35 in wxEvtHandler::ProcessEventIfMatches(wxEventTableEntryBase         const&, wxEvtHandler*, wxEvent&) ()
    from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwx_baseu-2.8.so.0
```

Comment: Where do you get the segfault?

Comment: @H2CO3: As soon as I enter text after pressing *New button*.

Comment: @Robin92 - I think H2CO3 is asking what line number your debugger reports it at. Is the line you added a comment at your hunch or what the debugger said?

Comment: @Flexo I don't use the debugger. When I comment out ``if (str.Len() > 0) list->InsertItems(1, &str, 0);`` segfault doesn't occur.

Comment: @Robin92 - commenting out the line proves nothing - it looks like you're seeing *undefined behaviour* which can manifest itself in strange ways, including "blaming" any other line of code. I'd suggest you build with debug symbols and run it in gdb and/or valgrind.

Comment: @Flexo: just added *gdb* reports

Comment: that's not the most interesting line of output from gdb - try looking `up` a few frames to the most recent line of your code. Print the value of `list` - I'm guessing it's `NULL` when you make that call. (Might not be, might be an invalid pointer)

Comment: @Flexo It may seem odd but how do I use symbol table with *gdb*?

Comment: @Flexo: Added *gdb* output you asked for

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Thanks to many pieces of advice I was able to successfully resolve the issue. It was caused by directly connecting buttons to functions. It seems that each button *must have a corresponding* identifier.

So this is wrong:

```
button = new wxButton(this, wxID_ANY, wxT("label"));
(...)
button->Connect(wxEVT_COMMAND_BUTTON_CLICKED, (wxObjectEventFunction) &CWindow::OnClick);
```

And this is good:

```
button = new wxButton(this, EVT_OnClick, wxT("label"));
(...)
Connect(EVT_OnClick, wxEVT_COMMAND_BUTTON_CLICKED, (wxObjectEventFunction) &CWindow::OnClick);
```

Comment: This is a very BAD IDEA.  You should keep your control IDs separate from your event ids.   Please look at the samples provided in the distribution and base your applications on these until you get a feel for how to do things in the wxWidgets idiom.

Comment: bad? this is exacly how this is done in the mentioned tutorial!

Comment: Not so.  Please look at the tutorial.  You will see that the IDs chosen for buttons and other widgets are NOT using event ids. For example ID_RENAME.

Comment: BTW, the tutorial you mention is by someone called Jan Bodnar who, AFAIK, is not connected in any official capacity with wxWidgets.  I recommend you look at the sample apps that come with the wxWidgets distro - the code there is more similar to that which many people working with wxWidgets use

Comment: @ravenspoint Name is just a name :) I can even name integer *character* and that doesn't change it's a integer.

Comment: I really hope that I never have to maintain any code you have written.

Answer (score 0):

From the debug output you have posted, your problem is not with using listbox but with using wxFrame.  I would guess that you have messed up the handling of wxFrame in your wxApp instance.

I suggest you start again, beginning with the minimal sample and building up your application step by step from there.

Comment: OK, place a breakpoint on the line and check that the value of the list pointer is sensible.

Comment: The problem is that *this is a minimal sample*. I've got no more code but *MyApp* class inheriting from *wxApp*. This class just can't be messed up, can it? From debugger output I understand that `$1 = (wxListBox *) 0x0` means my **list** variable points to *NULL*. Okay, so why ``list->Append("first entry")`` works in constructor?

Comment: Did you start with the minimal sample provided in the distribution?  It sure does not look like you did.  In the sample, the main frame is named MyFrame.  Calling the main frame CWindow is not idiomatic wxWidgets coding.